# xampp server is redirecting localhost to https://www.localhost

Tags: apache, xampp

Can someone shed some light on this? Googling this in multiple ways yielded some discussion about the browser forcing this, but I've turned off any prediction services, specifically:

- Use a web service to help resolve navigation errors
- Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar

And I have a single line in my etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

Comment: Remove caching from browser and try again

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use 127.0.0.1 directly ?